# Compatibility problems with IE when trying to download canvas

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I'm having issues with Internet Explorer and Canvas.  When I test this in any other browser it works.  It is just IE that is giving me fits.
This is where my Javascript function is implemented.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var szorientation;
   szorientation="l";

/*****************************************************************
* This is the function that will take care of image extracting and
* setting proper filename for the download.
* IMPORTANT: Call it from within a onclick event.
*****************************************************************/
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    link.download = filename;
}

function begin(){
   initcanvas();
}
</script>
```

And here is where it gets called.  Where am I going wrong?

```
<script>
//Download image to user
    document.getElementById('myalink').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'memcanvas', 'mypic.jpg');
}, false);

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);
function domloaded(){
    // your code here.
   begin(); 
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **What version** of internet explorer? IE major versions have substantial differences regarding the feature set they support and because the IE version is bound to the Windows versions, older versions are still in regular use.

Comment: Version was IE11.  I swore it was tested back in November and worked fine.  But my searching shows me and was confirmed that support is shoddy.  So it may have worked, IE11 maybe had some update and now it doesn't work.  Wouldn't put it past MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not yet support the `download` attribute so your code won't work in IE.

You could use this great workaround by Eli Grey to let IE users download your canvas to their local drive:

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Or you could go "old-school" and open up `canvas.toDataURL` as an image in another browser tab and let your users 'right-click-save-as' that image.

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying it out now.